# CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse vs Base64.decodeBase64, what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography

Want to understand how these two are different? Or they are same?

```
var key2 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(apiKey);
```

&

```
byte[] decodedBase64APIKeyByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(apiKey);
```

I have gone through the APIs of both but seems like both are doing conversions but my question is would the conversion be same for same input?

Will the output for both would be same?

Comment: Is that the Apache API you're using for Java?

Comment: Yes, it is commons-codec.

Comment: *"would the conversion be same for same input?"* --- Why don't you try it and see for yourself? --- Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort" (quoting tooltip of down-vote button).

Answer (score -1):

Both decode normal base64 with the default base64 alphabet including possible padding characters at the end.

There are a few differences however.

- Documentation: The commons-codec one is at least somewhat documented.
- The input: The commons-codec allows base64 and removes line endings and such (required for e.g. MIME decoding). A quick look at the CryptoJS code shows that it requires base64 without whitespace. So the Java based decoder allows different forms of input.
- The implementation: The CryptoJS parsing brings tears to my eyes, and not of joy. It has terrible performance, if just on how it handles the base 64 without streaming. It even is stupid enough to use an `indexOf` to lookup possible padding characters *up front*, which is both woefully bad *and* non-performant. Apache's implementation is only slightly better. Both should only be used for relatively small amounts of data.
- The output: The CryptoJS returns a *word-array* while the commons-codec one returns a byte array. For keys this doesn't matter much, as Java usually expects a byte array for `SecretKeySpec` while CryptoJS directly uses a word array as key.